# Convert DATE_FORMAT to Y-m-d? Using Larave Eloquent Raw Select

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently I have this eloquent select in laravel

`$queryBooking = Booking::where('id',$id)->select('starts_at','ends_at')->first();`

Now I want to put specific format to `starts_at` and `ends_at` using this format `Y-m-d`

Data should be shown somethings like this `2020-05-29` `(Y-m-d)`

How can I do that using laravel eloquent?

**UPDATE**

tried the answer of spiny did some modification.

```
 $queryBooking = Booking::where('id',$id)->select('starts_at','ends_at')->first();

 $booking = PropertyBooking::where('property_id',$queryBooking->property_id)
    ->selectRaw(
        'DATE_FORMAT(`starts_at`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS `starts_at`, DATE_FORMAT(`ends_at`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS `ends_at`'
    )->get();

    return view('admin.pages.property_request.edit', compact('property_request','booking'));
```

in my blade tried to log it using js says like this

[image]

Comment: `date('Y-m-d',strtotime($queryBooking->starts_at))` try this way.

Comment: It will give me  the expected output but I'm trying to work around the eloquent way..

Answer (score 0):

Just add some properties to your booking.
The date attribute converts the column to carbon.
The dateFormat attribute is the default format for converting dates to String

example

```
class Booking extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['starts_at','ends_at'];
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
    ....
}
```

Comment: Hi how can I apply this to my query? If I already have that `protected` on my ` model`

Comment: sry for my mistake
$queryBooking->starts_at->format('Y-m-d);

Comment: It says, trailing data.. Hmm

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```php
->selectRaw(
    'DATE_FORMAT(`starts_at`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS `starts_at`, DATE_FORMAT(`ends_at`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS `ends_at`'
)
```

Also you can use it as a scope:

```php
public function scopeSelectStartEndDates($query) {
    return $query->selectRaw(
        'DATE_FORMAT(`starts_at`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS `starts_at`, DATE_FORMAT(`ends_at`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS `ends_at`'
    );
}
```

```php
$model = Model::selectStartEndDates()->first();
```

Comment: `selectRaw` would be the answer but still I get the timestampp. It includes the time, it should be the YYYY-MM-DD only. :(

Comment: If so, you do smth wrong, dude. Could you provide the code with my example?

Comment: Your result shows `$queryBooking` and not `$booking` because `$queryBooking->property_id` is null (you didn't get it from select of `$queryBooking`). So, be more attentive and add it to query select first: `$queryBooking = Booking::where('id',$id)->select('property_id', 'starts_at','ends_at')->first();` ;)