# JSON Field with date format using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

As of now I can get the json format of my data using this code

```
    var bookingReserve = ['{!! $booking !!}'];
    var json = JSON.parse(bookingReserve);
    console.log(json);
```

and output like this

[image]

What I need to do is to generate json format based on the data thrown by `bookingReserve`

and

set date format `Y-m-d` to `starts_at` and `ends_at`

Unfortunately I can't filter the date format of the fields using laravel as I ask here

[Convert DATE_FORMAT to Y-m-d? Using Larave Eloquent Raw Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61767273/convert-date-format-to-y-m-d-using-larave-eloquent-raw-select/61771726?noredirect=1#comment109262722_61771726)

So what I'm trying to do is to generate json format and set `Y-m-d` date format for both `fields` using javascript

Comment: The ideal solution is to have your backend use a date format that JavaScript can understand, eg ISO 8601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const formatDate = dateString => {
    const d = new Date(dateString)
    return `${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth()}-${d.getDate()}`
}

formatted = json.map(obj =>  {
    return {
        starts_at: formatDate(obj.starts_at),
        ends_at: formatDate(obj.ends_at)
    }

})
```

Or with your case, just need to trim after space.

```
formatted = json.map(obj =>  {
    return {
        starts_at: obj.starts_at.split(" ")[0],
        ends_at: obj.ends_at.split(" ")[0]
    }

})
```

Comment: Been working on this since yesterday spent multiple hours. You saved me today! Thankyou